# NerdTree copy command in Windows 7

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I don't see the menu option for `Copy` command. Here is the menu that I see on my Windows 7 machine:

```
NERDTree Menu. Use j/k/enter and the shortcuts indicated
==========================================================
> (a)dd a childnode
  (m)ove the curent node
  (d)elete the curent node
```

According to the plugin [documentation](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), the `Copy` command is not supported on all platforms.

```
A textual filesystem menu is provided which allows you to create/delete/move file 
and directory nodes as well as copy (for supported OSs)
```

Has anybody managed to get this to work in Windows?

Comment: Have you already tried to push `c` at that prompt?

Comment: Yes, pressing `c` has no effect.

Comment: Apparently, [others are facing the same issue](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/152) but nobody seems to care. Also, see [this post](http://got-ravings.blogspot.fr/2008/07/windows-copying-commands-suck-giant.html) by NERDTree's author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause for the issue is discussed in detail(rather colorfully) in this [blog post](http://got-ravings.blogspot.fr/2008/07/windows-copying-commands-suck-giant.html).(ht [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl)).
I managed to find a solution by using the `cp.exe` shipped with [msygit](http://msysgit.github.com/).

**Ensure `cp.exe` is in your path**

The `cp.exe` file can be found in `<GIT_HOME>\bin` directory. My path didn't not contain the `<GIT_HOME>\bin` directory. So I copied `cp.exe` and `msys-1.0.dll` to a directory in my path.

**Set the `g:NERDTreeCopyCmd` variable**

Add the line below to the end of the `_vimrc` file

```
let g:NERDTreeCopyCmd= 'cp -r '
```

**Fix the implementation of  `s:Path.copy` function.**

Replace the lines 2297-2299 of `~/vimfiles/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim` (assuming you used pathogen for managing vim plugins)

- Replace the lines 2297-2299

  ```
    let dest = s:Path.WinToUnixPath(a:dest)

    let cmd = g:NERDTreeCopyCmd . " " . escape(self.str(), s:escape_chars) . " " . escape(dest, s:escape_chars)
  ```
- With the lines below

  ```
    let dest = a:dest
    let cmd = 0
    if s:running_windows
        let cmd = g:NERDTreeCopyCmd . '"' . self.str() . '" "' . dest . '"'
    else
        let cmd = g:NERDTreeCopyCmd . " " . escape(self.str(), s:escape_chars) . " " . escape(dest, s:escape_chars)
    endif
  ```

Comment: This tip doesn't work anymore as is. You have to edit vimfiles/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim, around line 166. And use "nerdtree#runningWindows()" instead of "s:running_windows"

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by installing [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow)

`choco install -y gow`

Then adding this line to vim

`let g:NERDTreeCopyCmd= 'cp -r'`

Thanks: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/152

PS: The choco command comes from https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: It works! However, I get the error `NERDTree: Could not copy node` when the file I'm trying to copy has spaces in it... Any advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I added the following to my vimrc

```
if (has('win32'))
    " let g:NERDTreeCopyCmd= 'copy '
    let g:NERDTreeCopyCmd= 'Copy-Item -Recurse '
endif
```

First one works, but I set it to the second, I think you need that for copying directories properly..

I just tried delete, and that also fails. Guess we need a similar workaround.

**EDIT: Sorry, you will have to set your shell to run PowerShell for the second command to work!**